# How to monitor the process in Linux and catch the unexpected termination?

Tags: linux, bash, process

### Environment description

At first, I execute a bash-shell in background. And write the **stdout** and **stderr** to the log file `./out`.

```
(bash ./myshell.sh > ./out 2>&1)&
```

In the shell will run multiple programs like **Node.js** sequentially.

```
node program.js --number 1
node program.js --number 2
node program.js --number 3
...
```

I can check the progress status by `ps`, a sample below:

```
$ ps ux | grep shell
user 10001 (skipped...)  bash ./myshell.sh

$ ps ux | grep node
user 10002 (skipped...)  node program.js --number 1
```

---

### Problem

And then, maybe run the **2nd program** in progress, the processes will be killed (or terminated) both.

#### Clue 1

We can conjecture **3rd program** will launch because **2nd program** stopped. In fact, **bash-shell** and **2nd program** are terminated both by unknown reason.

#### Clue 2

I had left the **stderr** via `(... > ./out 2>&1)&`. But I cannot get any message from the log file. I just know **2nd program** was stopped in a moment.

---

### Conclusion

I want to find a tool that can monitor my process by specific **process id** or the others similar solution to do it.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You might want to write your own shell like program

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether a process still exists using its ID, then you can use something like this:

`kill -0 $pid`

The `-0` here will negate the kill command, and instead give the output.

Alternatively, if you actually want to act on the exit code, ignoring the `kill` output, you could do something more programmatic:

`if ! kill $pid > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Could not send SIGTERM to process $pid" >&2
fi`